# How can I inspect page resources in Firefox?

Tags: file, firefox, resources

In Chromium / Chrome I can use "Inspect element" to [view a list of the current page's resources](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel#inspecting-page-resources), including JS, images, videos. Basically, all files that have been downloaded in service of that page.

When I "Inspect element" in Firefox I can't find an equivalent. Am I missing it, or is there another way to access the list of files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. From the Tools menu, pick *Page Info*
2. In the *Page Info* window, select the *Media* tab

...the list of files downloaded for that page will appear under the *Media* tab.

Comment: That seems to be outdated. See @Raymond's answer which worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

In order to view resources like js or css files, you would select *Network* in the developer tools panel to open the Network Monitor. This will show **all** resources downloaded by the page (including images, media etc.)

From there you can narrow your search based on the type of resource you're looking for by selecting the appropriate tab at the top of the window. To inspect its contents, select the resource from the list and click the *Response* tab in the window that appears to the right.

Comment: Strangely, my Firefox Inspector's _Network_ / _Images_ tab appears __blank__. I had to poke through the HTML source to find the image I wanted in a page. Chrome's Inspector has the _Application_ tab, from there you simply scroll down in the left hand pane for _Frames_ / _Images_ and you will see all images loaded in the page.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, press 'F12' to open developer tools then select 'Network'. Under 'Network' select the filter labelled 'Images'. Reload your page and the images will be listed there along with their links. You can open them in a new tab and save them on your device.

Answer (score -1):

After opening the Inspect Element console; Look for the Toolbox options at the TOP RIGHT CORNER (highlighted in BLUE as shown in the Picture link below)

[image: Toolbox options image]

Click on it and under the "***Default Firefox Developer Tools***" ; Click on the ones that you want to get displayed. (As per the link you gave for the Google Chrome that displayed the "Resources" - the equivalent in Firefox would be "Storage", as shown below

[image: Storage image]

*Toolbox Options--> Storage*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm afraid these are instructions for cookies and local storage, which does not include JS, images and videos (as requested)